# FileHelpers read csv with FieldQuoted having " character in multi lines filed

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have a trouble with read csv file with FileHelpers library like that:

1. I have a csv file with some lines, if the first line have " character and the second line have " character too, then the second line will be the last column of the first line after read.
2. If my csv file have some lines, all line have single line and one of them have " character, then this line will be ignore.

Really need help!

Here is my class

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
[IgnoreFirst()]

public sealed class MyClass
{

    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.AllowForBoth)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public String NAME;

    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.AllowForBoth)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public String NOTES;
}
```

And my read file code:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog
{
    Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv",
    FilterIndex = 0,
    CheckFileExists = true,
    RestoreDirectory = true
};

if (ofd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if (AppSetting.IsFileLocked(ofd.FileName))
    {
        //file in is use
        MessageUtility.ShowNotify(LanguagesMessage.GetLanguagesMessage("USING"));
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
        if (f.Extension != ".csv")
        {
            MessageUtility.ShowNotify(MsgFormatFile);
            return;
        }
    }

    var _curr_encoding = SimpleHelpers.FileEncoding.DetectFileEncoding(ofd.FileName);

    if (_curr_encoding == null)
    {
        MessageUtility.ShowNotify(MsgFormatFile);
        return;
    }

    if (_curr_encoding.CodePage == _encoding_export_import.CodePage)
    {
        _curr_encoding = _encoding_export_import;
    }
    else
    {
        _curr_encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(_curr_encoding.CodePage);
    }

    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<MyClass>(_curr_encoding);
    engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
    engine.Encoding = _curr_encoding;
    engine.AfterReadRecord += Engine_AfterReadRecord;

    List<MyClass> lstDataImports = engine.ReadFile(ofd.FileName).ToList();

    if (engine.ErrorManager.ErrorCount > 0)
    {
        MessageUtility.ShowNotify(MsgFormatFile);
        engine.ErrorManager.SaveErrors("Errors.txt");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (lstDataImports.Count() < 1)
        {
            MessageUtility.ShowNotify(LanguagesMessage.GetLanguagesMessage_SM("MY_ERROR"));
            return;
        }
    }
    if (!ValidateHeader(engine.HeaderText))
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: IsFileLocked ? DetectFileEncoding?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior, when configuring `MyClass` with `QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth` and `MultilineMode.AllowForBoth`.

Explanation: you allow quoting of those fields (by attributing `QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth`) and allow for a record to continue in the next line (by attributing `MultilineMode.AllowForBoth`).

You have to also remember, if that's not clear, that quoting is the act of put quotation mark before and after the record you wish to read.

Comment: csv sample with quoting and next line ?